# Accessing files in my program folder in a more pythonic way

Tags: python, filepath

My program uses a csv file to load up some initialization info.

I have a config file that loads data from this csv file. I am building a web app as part of this program, and the config file is accessed from various points in the entire application.

This program must operate cross-platform.

**Problem:** Depending on who calls the config file and where the caller lives in the file tree, the csv operation is throwing `IOError` errors. The csv data isn't even accessed, but on import of the config file, the csv read portion executes anyway.

The code below is rife with Band-Aids...

```
# print os.getcwd()
try:
    with open('value_addresses.csv') as file: #  located in code folder. used extensively below
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        lines = [l for l in reader]
except IOError:
    try:
        with open('_code/value_addresses.csv') as file: #
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            lines = [l for l in reader]
    except IOError:
        with open('../_code/value_addresses.csv') as file: #
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            lines = [l for l in reader]
```

Comment: Have you thought of using absolute paths instead of relative paths?

Comment: Could you post a trace?  Is this just a file not found, so you are looking for it?

Comment: @DarinDouglass That is not an option, because this has to work on both my development machine and the server and any other machine it ends up on. The file structure within the main folder will not change, though.

Comment: @woot I don't have a trace right now. It is a "file not found" error. But I'm not "looking" for it. The file lives in one known spot within my folder structure

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor the common code into a function.

```
def read_file(path):
  with open(path) as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    lines = [l for l in reader]
  return lines

try:
  read_file("value_addresses.csv")
except IOError:
  try:
    read_file('_code/value_addresses.csv')
  except IOError:
    read_file('../_code/value_addresses.csv')
```

You can further simplify this by recursively figuring out the path to `value_addresses.csv`.

Comment: This increases the number of code lines EDIT: nevermind. I should count better

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
from os.path import join
import csv

def myopen( filename, possible_dirs, mode ):
    for dir in possible_dirs:
        try: 
            return open(join(dir,filename),mode)
        except IOError:
            pass
    raise IOError('File not found.')

with myopen('value_addresses.csv',['.','_code','../_code'],'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    lines = [l for l in reader]
```

Although maybe you want to look more into the specific IOError you are getting, but either way this is the general approach I would take.